# Android Google Maps v2 map doesnt refresh when moving

Tags: android, google-maps

I use a Google Map within my Android app to show a couple of destinations, including a route to the different destinations. When the user moves from point A to point B, the map only reloads sometimes, seemingly at random times. Sometimes, the map doesn't reload for minutes or not at all. As soon as the user touches(scrolls or zooms) the map reloads, but not on its own.
One can still somehow use it, since a very low resolution version of the whole area was loaded, but not the high quality map that is loaded as soon as the user interacts with the map...
(Sometimes the map is updated automatically though...)

Is there a way to load map data manually? (onCameraChanged for example)
Or is there a setting which might help?

Thanks,
J

Comment: maybe you have slow internet connection, and what is your test device?

Comment: Slow Internet connection cant really be the problem, since it updates pretty quickly, once the user interacts with the map...I have the issue on several devices (Nexus7 (2nd), Galaxy Tab 10, some Asus tablet...)

Comment: There are two convenience methods for the common position changes. CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(LatLng) gives you a CameraUpdate that changes the camera's latitude and longitude, while preserving all other properties. CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng, float) gives you a CameraUpdate that changes the camera's latitude, longitude and zoom, while preserving all other properties.

Comment: The camera updates just fine. The problem is, that the new areas are of the map are not loaded